# How to reclassify multiple ring buffer using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, buffer, reclassify

I want to automate some simple procedure in ArcGIS 10.1:

1. create a multi-ring buffer around a point at distances 500, 1500, 2500, 3000, 10000 m.
2. convert to raster
3. reclassify the multiple ring raster in 1,2,3,4, and 5.

My problem is that in the ModelBuilder when I get asked to enter the Reclass field, which I defined as "distances" it does not appear. Only a value field appears showing 10000.

What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: When you run Polygon to Raster, under Value field you need to specify "distance" (if you haven't changed the default of Multiple Ring Buffer). Then, the new raster will have as many unique values as there were distances, specified under field Value. This Value field is the one to reclassify, but until you run Polygon to Raster, ArcMap won't be able to tell which old values (distances) to reclassify. But as you know which distances you have specified before, you can manually set this up using Add Entry, one for each distance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the Field Value I defined of course "distance" (or the default). However, when I pass to the reclass field (reclassify tool) there appears only "value" and it does not show my distance ranges.

Comment: Like I've said, until you have run the buffer tool and Polygon to Raster, distances won't appear there. You can first run both Multiple Ring Buffer and Polygon to Raster by right clicking them and pushing "Run", and then the distance values will appear in the Reclassify tool.

Comment: Then I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you run Polygon to Raster, under Value field you need to specify "distance" (if you haven't changed the default of Multiple Ring Buffer).
2. Then, the new raster will have as many unique values as there were unique distances, specified under field Value. This Value field is the one to reclassify, but until you run Polygon to Raster, ArcMap won't be able to tell which old values (distances) to reclassify.

At this stage you have two options:

1. As you know which distances you have specified before, you can manually set this up using Add Entry, one for each distance.
2. Alternatively, First run both Multiple Ring Buffer and Polygon to Raster by right clicking them and pushing "Run", and then the distance values will appear in the Reclassify tool.